# Does ADT support Java 7 API

Tags: android, api, adt, java-7

Do Android Developers Tools support JAVA 7 API up to this date?
I'm trying to build an Android app using JAVA 7 and I was wondering about this thing.

Comment: Java 7 is now [officially supported](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Using-sourceCompatibility-1.7). To the mods @tuxdude - what exactly is not a real question here? It is a very precise and very relevant and real question that keeps many busy (think e.g of compatibility to external jar files), and since the question's closed we cannot update it to the current status.

Comment: Agreed. Very ignorant to say this is not a real question. Very, very, very ignorant of the Android landscape. Not only is this a real question, there are significant levels of complexity to this question.

Comment: Mods please reopen this question

Answer (score 32, accepted):

While you can *write* code in Java 7, the Android Systems that run it only support upto Java 6, so 7 features like switch-case on Strings fail.

[As of Build tools 19](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Using-sourceCompatibility-1.7), Java 7 is now supported.

Comment: Could you elaborate the `==` comparison remark? From what I understand, using the `==` operator on Strings succeeds on Java 6 as well as Java 7: it returns true if they are the same instance, and false otherwise.

Comment: @pimmhogeling It compares the memory address of the objects, not their values. So if you have two different strings that both have the same value, it will return false. equals() compares the value.

Comment: Yes, exactly as I would expect it to work. But it works that way on both Java 6 and Java 7, doesn't it?

Comment: @pimm on java 7, == compares the values, not the instance.

Comment: The Java 7 book by Jay Bryant (1430236868 or 9781430236863) explicitly says == compares the instances (page 63). On the other hand, I found different people around the web who say you are correct.

Is this clarified in a spec somewhere?

Comment: [It's now supported](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Using-sourceCompatibility-1.7)!

Comment: Is Java 7 actually supported in Eclipse ADT or only in Android Studio?

Comment: [Java 7 language features are now supported by Eclipse ADT](https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#notes) as well (as of March)

Comment: What api versions does the Java 7 support extend to?

Answer (score 5):

No, the [android documentation](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) is pretty clear about this. Only Java 6.

Also, be sure to download the Oracle JDK 6 (the Java Runtime is not sufficient).

Comment: This answer is outdated now.