# Can I remove Java 6 and Android still working?

Tags: java, android

I have Java 6, and I am working on [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) for Android programming. I installed Java 7 and all of a sudden, the Java website told me that I have versions that I can remove. This is the photo:

[image]

If I removed these versions, can my Eclipse and Android programs keep working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eclipse and Android will work with Java 6 or 7.  You just need one of the two running (if you don't have Java at all they won't work).  Building the Android platform is another issue entirely...

Keep in mind that Android runs Java 6 so you won't be able to use any Java 7 runtime features that are not backwards compatible.

See [here for eclipse compatibility](http://eclipse.org/org/press-release/20110929_indigosr1.php)

See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15848376/150771) for Android compatibility.

Comment: so i can remove them now and nothing bad for my application will happen, right?

Comment: That's right, as long as you have at least one version of Java running and your PATH adjusted accordingly so the jre, jdk can be found by the requisite programs.

Answer (score 1):

You only need one version of Java installed. Keep the most recent one and remove the others.

Why doesn't Java uninstall the previous version if you install a newer version? First, compatibility reasons. Second, there might be programs running, and one does not want for example Eclipse or the Android environment to crash if you install a new version.

Comment: so i can remove them now and nothing bad for my application will happen, right ? ? ?